# How mapped override field to database in Core EF Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a abstract base Class that has the name property and the [NotMapped] attribute

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    abstract public string name { get; set; }
}
```

There is also a subclass that inherits from EntityBase

```
public class Person: EntityBase
{
    public override string name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

I execute **add-migration Migration20191106** and **Update-Database** generate migration file and mapped to Database, but it's not create **name** field, I try change EntityBase class:

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual string name { get; set; }
```

and change Person class:

```
[Required]
public override string name { get; set; }
```

But get the same result.

I want to know how can the name field with [NotMapped] attribute mapped to the Database, Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Wades,

{NotMapped] tells EF not to add to the database.

Comment: yes I know, so I'm user override this attribute of parent class in Person, but it's invalid